# Unable to write date from string to TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

No matter what variation of code to display the date is used it won't set the text of the TextView.

```
public void setDate (View view){
        TextView dateView;
        Date dNow = new Date();
        String str = String.format("Current Date : %tc", dNow);
        dateView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_Text_View);
        dateView.setText("The date is" + str);

    }
```

Cheers,
Harris

Comment: I have fixed minor English issues.  It would others to help you faster if you supplied the minimum code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `dateView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_Text_View);`->`view.findViewById`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating TextView `onCreate()`, you should call `setDate()` method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

    TextView dateView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_Text_View);
    setDate(dateView);
}

public void setDate (TextView view){
    String str = String.format("%tc", new Date());
    view.setText("The date is " + str);
}
```